# How to disable the forward / back buttons during video playback on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cordova, html5-video

I have a PhoneGap app that plays an HTML5  tag.  Upon playing the video, the native iOS video player is invoked with prev / play / next buttons.  If I click the next button, since there is no next video, the app just goes to a black screen.  Is there a way to either disable these button or handle their event properly?

Comment: did u find a solution yet? having the same issue :/

Comment: No, I never did find a solution.  I ended up having to use the native player for the project I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

something like this work?

```
var video = document.getElementById("video"); // assuming "video" is your videos' id
video.removeAttribute("controls");
```

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to help.  I believe that would remove the native controls on a <video> tag that is played within an HTML page, in the scenario where you would want to implement your own custom control elements.  On an iPhone, (I believe) the video automatically always goes to native fullscreen.  Unfortunately, the native fullscreen has these prev/next buttons, which when clicked, go nowhere and provide a rather unpleasant user experience.